# Practical, or theoretical - which do we prefer?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Sorry, this is going to be another meta question about these two:

[Pilot passed out in a small GA plane. What can a passenger do?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19636/pilot-passed-out-in-a-small-ga-plane-what-can-a-passenger-do)
[Can a passenger realistically replace suddenly incapacitated pilots?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8986/can-a-passenger-realistically-replace-suddenly-incapacitated-pilots)

(Full disclosure: I am biased, I currently have the accepted answer on the former)

---

The way I see it the latter question is asking about a *theoretical situation* (It even opens with "Yes, this is a question from the movies"). Even though the title uses the word "realistically", I don't believe anyone realistically believes a layman could fly a jet liner.

The former question is asking for practical, realistic things an inexperienced, but enthusiastic* person could do in an emergency situation.

It saddens me that the former question is very close to be closed as a dupe of the latter. I would much rather see good, practical information on this site than whimsical, movie-related, thought experiments.

What are your thoughts?

<sub>* has some experience on a sim, has flown in a GA aircraft a few times, understands some practicalities of flight</sub>

Answer (score 5):

For me, those questions are essentially asking the same thing: what can a passenger do in the case of pilot incapacitation? However, the first one is asking about a passenger (presumably in the right seat) in a light single-engined aircraft and the second one is asking about an airline passenger.

I think those scenarios are different enough that they should be separate questions: the actions in one case won't be the same as the other. For one thing, in the airliner scenario you have a lot more resources available: cabin crew (who should take charge of the situation anyway), other passengers, extensive cockpit automation etc. In a light single you might not even have a radio.

As for practical vs. theoretical, the GA scenario is practical enough that AOPA has an [online course](http://flash.aopa.org/asf/pinch_hitter/swf/flash.cfm?) for it; the airline scenario is so wildly improbable (even considering [Helios 522](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios_Airways_Flight_522)) that there isn't much point in worrying about it. In other words, those two scenarios are inherently practical and theoretical. Practically speaking, that is :-)

Comment: Ok, so you're just agreeing with me right? Both questions should remain open, and one is paractical whilst the other is (mostly) theoretical.

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, exactly.